# gdal installed but not working in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, gdal

I installed gdal using `conda install -c conda-forge gdal` in my Jupyter terminal, but when I run the following code:

```
import gdal
gdal.Open('/Users/alyse/ldem.img') 
gdal.Translate('/Users/alyse/ldem.img')
mpimg.read('/Users/alyse/ldem.img')
```

I get the following error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gdal'.`
welp. If anyone has any advice I would very much appreciate! I am a coding beginner.

Answer (score 4):

Try this: `from osgeo import gdal`, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I did face a number of issues with gdal + jupyer notebooks. In the end, I created a virtual environment in Anaconda, conda install -c conda-forge gdal and all is working fine now.